# Snort: Cannot decode data link type 127 reading a pcapng file

Tags: snort

I've captured on my wifi some days ago and now I want snort to analyse the capture to detect any problem. However, when I run `snort -l ./snort-log -b -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -r captura-analisar.pcapng` it stops with

> ERROR: Cannot decode data link type 127
>
> Fatal Error, Quitting..

I guess this is happening because there is some encrypted 802.11 data in the file. Not all packets are encrypted though. If it is the case, how to set snort to ignore the encrypted data and analyse only the decrypted? Or if it isn't the case, what is the problem?

Comment: The  problem is that you did not capture at the ethernet layer. See https://bhumishgajjar.wordpress.com/tag/enable-non-ether-decoders/ for more information on this.

Comment: in my case, the wifi interface captured was called `wlp6s0`, I added the option `-i wlp6s0` and still had the same error

Comment: The `-i` option is only for live capture and does not affect the interpretation of the pcap. Did you actually read the article I've linked to?

Comment: yes, i've read, correct me if I get something wrong but if I live capture on the wifi interface, wouldn't snort then need the EAPOL handshakes to decrypt the packets? According to this: https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11

Comment: The main point is that the you've sniffed at the wrong data link layer, i.e. a layer unsupported by snort. The used data link layer is not a per packet setting but is global for the whole pcap file. For processing with snort you should sniff at the ethernet layer, i.e. plain interface with no monitor mode or anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

from what you described, I understood:

- You already have PCAP files to analyse with Snort (so you are not running in live mode but reading back previously created captures). Therefore the switch `-i` does not apply in this case.
- Snort aborts with the message: `ERROR: Cannot decode data link type 127`
- When you mention "detect any problem", I assume you are specifically looking for malware communication (and not investigation network issues, eg. layer-2 issues with your Wifi!).

First, you need to remove radiotap link encapsulation by rewriting the layer-2 link type into something Snort can easily cope with, eg. link-type `ether`

For that you can use `editcap` tool from Wireshark project.

`editcap captura-analisar.pcapng -T ether captura-1.pcap`, where:

- `-T ether`: sets the encapsulation type of the output file to `ether`.

By the way, if your version of Snort does not read PCAPNG files, you can also convert it with `editcap` adding parameter `-F pcap`

`editcap captura-analisar.pcapng -F pcap -T ether captura-1.pcap`

From now on you can run snort over your PCAPs files with a command such as:

`snort -A console -k none -K none -c snort.conf -r captura-1.pcap`

where:

- `-A`: issues alerts to the console
- `-K`: logging-mode, `none` will not create PCAPs from the alerts, while `pcap` will do so. Use accordingly.
- `-k`: checksum mode, ignore checksum validation.
- `-c`: your snort config file containing variables, pre-process options, rules.
- `-r`: read PCAP. be aware of other options to read bunch of pcap files, such as `--pcap-dir=/home/foo/pcaps` or `--pcap-list="foo1.pcap foo2.pcap foo3.pcap"`

Does it make sense?

Kind regards
J.C.

- `editcap` is part of Wireshark, see: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolseditcap.html

PS: you can inspect the properties of PCAP files with `capinfos -M captura.pcap`. This shows information on encapsulation, amount of packets captured, start/end date of capture, duration, etc.